# Unwanted Tkinter button click

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I haven't done any GUI projects for over 20 years, so as a learning project I'm coding a simple calculator in Tkinter. I'm using functions to generate repeating code for buttons; but the button press code is behaving in a way I didn't expect. Buttons 1 - 3 do what you'd expect - print their number in the text window, but button 4 executes immediately - without any button press. When I run the code below 4 is already displayed in the text box. Why? What am I doing wrong?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

app = Tk()

display = Text(app, background="white", bd=5, height=4, width=30)

# Function to generate buttons
def but(n):
    return ttk.Button(app, text=n)
# Function for button press
def butPress(n):
    return display.insert(INSERT,n)

b1 = but(1)
b2 = but(2)
b3 = but(3)
b4 = but(4)

display.grid(row=0)
b1.grid(row=1, column=0)
b2.grid(row=1, column=1)
b3.grid(row=1, column=2)
b4.grid(row=2, column=0)

def but1():
    display.insert(INSERT,'1')

def but2():
    display.insert(INSERT,'2')

def but3():
    display.insert(INSERT,'3')

b1.configure(command=but1)
b2.configure(command=but2)
b3.configure(command=but3)
b4.configure(command=butPress(4))

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: you are assigning a function call to `b4`, instead of assigning the function `b4` to b called with arg `4` upon pressing. Try using `b4.configure(command=lambda: butPress(4))`. You can do that with the other buttons too, or assign them all in a loop using `return ttk.Button(app, text=n, command= lambda arg=n: butPress(n))`

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Should be `lambda arg=n: butPress(arg)`.

Comment: haha, yes, good catch @acw1668, thank you!

Comment: Thanks guys, very neat solution :-)